# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript

Me da el error

`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Según algunas fuentes es porque la pagina devuelve 404, pero no he logrado encontrar una manera para evitar que de error

```
setInterval(function(){
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.user.setPresence(
                {
                    status: "online",
                    game: {
                        name: `Error conectando con la api`,
                        type: "PLAYING"             
                    }
                }
            );

            throw new Error('Error getting Minecraft server status...');

        }else{

            if(response == false){

                client.user.setPresence(
                    {
                        status: "online",
                        game: {
                            name: `Error conectando con la api`,
                            type: "PLAYING"             
                        }
                    }
                );       

            }else{

                console.log(response);
                body = JSON.parse(body); 

                if(status_writeline == `Somos ` + body.players.now + ` Personas en (Servidor)`){
                    status_writeline = `IP: (IP del servidor)`;
                } else {
                    status_writeline =  `Somos ` + body.players.now + ` Personas en (Servidor)`;
                }

                client.user.setPresence(
                    {
                        status: "online",
                        game: {
                            name: status_writeline,
                            type: "PLAYING"             
                        }
                    }
                );              
            }
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Como ven hago una request a una api.

Comment: Por favor lee  [ask], sin tu código poco podemos hacer

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del json que te devuelven? Por lo que parece es un problema de formato, quizás no llega bien formado

Comment: El problema no es el formato, el problema es que a veces la pagina envia 404, intento evitar que de error con validaciones pero no lo logro

Comment: Si te dice ese mensaje de error es porque la informacion que te devuevle no es un json correcto, haz un log de eso. Es raro que te devuelve una 404, si entra en el else

Comment: Me gustaría poder hacerle una edición a la pregunta pero no puedo porque la anterior edición no ha sido aprobada aún :c, por cierto tienes que poner que te devuelve body, por que de lo contrario estamos en la mismas, sin nada respecto a las pregunta.